# Different git commit origin master and my server

Tags: git, git-commit

In my local git,

```
~/my/local/dir/my-repo-name$ rev-parse HEAD
2978a05ecaa0657220b669fc60f127349f87faf4
```

However in my live-server, I had to `git stash`, and it gave the following:

```
myremote@mylive-website:~/mylive$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 9728f63 Merge branch 'master' of bitbucket.org:myname/my-repo-name
HEAD is now at 9728f63 Merge branch 'master' of bitbucket.org:myname/my-repo-name
myremote@mylive-website:~/mylive$ git rev-parse HEAD
1cb3966b518e0e31940407d53b981bbb58a62092
myremote@mylive-website:~/mylive$ git merge master
Already up-to-date.
```

So my local and live-server have different commit number. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to `git fetch` and then forward your branch to the most recent commit (e.g. by `merge --ff-only`)

Comment: or use      git pull

Answer (score 0):

I would do a `git pull --rebase`, in order to replay any local commit (not yet pushed) on top of the updated remote `origin/master` branch.

Then, you would be able to push back `master` to `origin`, without having to worry about `--ff` (since it would be fast-forward only) or forcing a push.